# Connect to Selenium webdriver URL through a proxy using Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, urllib3

I'm using the Python selenium language binding to connect to a remote webdriver through a proxy. I'm not concerned about the proxy configuration in the destination web browser, just the webdriver connection.
e.g.

```
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://mywebdriver:4444/wd/hub'...)
```

It seems the current implementation of the Selenium python module uses urllib3 for all underlying http requests:

selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py contains:

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager(timeout=self._timeout)
resp = http.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
```

however urllib3 does not seem to obey http_proxy or https_proxy environment variables. Instead it looks like you should use ProxyManager:

```
http = urllib3.ProxyManager('http://myproxy:3128/')
```

I'd like to try and use standard unmodified libraries as far as possible but it looks like this would involve me running with a customised version of the Selenium python library in order to get proxy support.

Is there something I've missed here? Are there any other ways of setting proxy details?